# Which $n$ can be expressed as $x^2 − y^2$?

Tags: number-theory

Which $n$ can be expressed as $x^2 − y^2$?

Attempt: Any number which is odd or or which is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Why would you think that? (It's the right answer, but that's more or less worthless without a supporting argument / proof.)

Comment: any number that is not a prime can  be expressed as N=x^2-y^2=(x-y)*(x+y)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. For odd numbers: What is the difference between $(n+1)^2$ and $n^2$?
2. For multiples of 4: What is the difference between $(n+1)^2$ and $(n-1)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

If the number can be written as $x^2-y^2$ then following can be possible:

If one of  $x,y$  is odd and other is even, the $x^2-y^2$ will be of the form $4k+1$ which is odd.

If $x$ and $y$ both are even, the $x^2-y^2$ will be of the form $4k$.

If $x,y$ are both odd the the $x^2-y^2$ will be of the form $4k+2m$.

These are only the possible conditions.

Comment: This is a necessary, but not sufficient condition.

Comment: No sure about that difference between two odd squares - such a difference is always divisible by $8$

Answer (score 0):

The squares mod $4$ are $0$ and $1$, so the differences of two squares, mod $4,$ can be only $0$, $1$, or $3$.

Comment: To clarify: (a) $0 = 1 - 1 = 0 - 0$, (b) $1 = 1 - 0$, and (c) $3 = 0 - 1$ are the only possible differences of two squares, mod 4.

Comment: This is a necessary, but not sufficient condition.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide the other direction. For an odd number we can write $2k + 1 = (k+1)^2 - k^2$. For a multiple of four we can write $4j = (j + 1)^2 - (j - 1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=n.$$

As a sum and a difference have the same parity, we can use any factorization $n=ab$ such that
$$n\text{ even}\to a\text{ even},b\text{ even}\to 4|n,\text{ or }\\n\text{ odd}\to a\text{ odd},b\text{ odd}.$$

Then
$$n=\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)^2.$$

In particular, $b=2$ or $b=1$ always work.